# How to boot Linux on a Mac with USB?

Tags: linux, mac, boot, usb

Although this question is even asked here before, the replies are outdated.

My Mac HD failed, an the machine does not boot anymore, but I absolutely need to recover the data in it. So I thought of booting it with Linux, and a damaged-disc reading app (safedisc for example).

But all the information I found about this is old, specially after the application named "Mac Linux USB Loader" got released, people stopped trying without it.

The thing is, that application is for OSX, but the mac as I stated, does not boot, my only working machine is a Windows 8 one (factory-modded UEFI...)

So, how I create a USB stick that boots a Mac so I can recover my data, using Windows?

Comment: You want to recover the data with Windows or do you want to know how to boot to Linux?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Take out old hard drive, put in new hard drive. Put old drive in USB enclosure. Boot Mac with Cmd/R at the chimes, use Internet Recovery to install new OS. Recover data from old drive over USB with the tool of your choice.

Comment: Yep, I did that Tetsujin. Didn't expect to have a new hard drive, thus why I don't mentioned I could try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this same problem and it is one of the most infuriating things so I understand where you're coming from. That being said the news I bring is not good.

So there are a number of reason this can be difficult to do.

- Lets start with the impossible. If you have a device before 2006.
  It's not possible. Sorry.

  If your device is after 2006 the games begin. So the most common
  problems:
- The device is not formated with GUID ([According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201663). I saw some tutorials talking about MBR). If you think it is double
  check.
- You're not holding booting to the USB. Hold option key and look for
  your device.
- The EFI support is creating problems.
- If the USB or USB port has connection issues of any kind.
- Not but Mac Linux USB loader might being doing some special things. So using it may be necessary in order to allow it to boot.
- And possibly you [can't / it's complicated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key)

I feel bad that there isn't one simple answer. Since these problems can be very machine dependent and I don't have much info to go off of I can't narrow it down further. I think your best bet right now is to but your Windows machine into Linux and follow [this tutorial](https://studyblast.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/guide-mac-os-x-lion-how-to-boot-a-linux-live-system-from-a-usb-drive-how-to-update-any-ocz-ssds-firmware/) ignoring the irrelevant parts. As mentioned in other answers pendrivelinux may work for you also.

While it appears you have an idea of how to recover your data Ramhound really wants me to tell you. So here it goes. Depending on how screwed up your drive is you may or may not get your data back.

The software option. Clone your drive using clonezilla. Just google [a tutorial](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone). Note the drive you're cloning onto must be equal or larger than the drive you're cloning from. After you have your cloned drive you should run [a data recovery tool](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/809671-get-your-data-back-with-linux-based-data-recovery-tools) on it. And kaboom. You got your files.

If your drive is screwed up to the point where your heads are broken or the platters are screwed up I have bad news. You're going to need to do a hardware recovery. This basically means you ship the hard drive to a company that takes it apart in a special clean room and then does a bunch of magic hooking it up to a head and reading it. Not only is the data not guaranteed to be there if the head scratched the daylights out of it but the process is expensive.

Comment: How old of a machine are you talking about? Any intel mac should be able to boot from usb, if not it will have a cd drive and you can boot from that.

Comment: @Griffin - Unless you had an Apple with an PowerPC processor what the author wants is certainly possible on any Apple with a x86 processor.  The very fact they want to use Windows seems to indicate they do have an Apple with a x86 processor, and even if it has a PowerPC processor there is a solution to his question.  It just does not involve Linux or Windows for obvious reasons.  So how does the author restore his file, your answer, fails to explain how he does that.

Comment: These were old. Like 5 years or so. And that's what we ended up doing. Now if it has an Intel chip its supposed to work but I after researching my specific machine I found that everyone else was having the same problem. I ended up using a CD but damn it was frustrating.

Comment: @Griffin - Just so you understand the reason I downvoted this question, the author obviously wants to restore his files, and this answer does not explain how he does that.  You are saying the author might have a hard time booting to a USB device, so explain, how they accomplish their task.

Comment: @Ramhound Nobody addressed that. Why haven't you downvoted them? Also the person asking the question already appears to understand how he will retrieve the files as he has mentioned software he will use.

Comment: @Griffin - Life is unfair.  You have more reputation.  Their answers will likely be caught by quality control anyways.  I am holding you to a higher level of quality.  Besides I have not had a chance to do so.

Comment: @Ramhound Fair enough for me.

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe fixed the question.

Comment: @Griffin Happy to once the author provides my requested clarification or you could fix the question or your answer or accept my feedback

Comment: @Ramhound Just for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but If you have an OSX iso image you can try your luck with rufus
https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Answer (score 0):

See [pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/). Any live USB created on a windows PC will be able to boot a mac computer. You just need a live usb creator for windows. The USB you create is bootable independently of the OS/Platform it was created on.

After creating your live usb on the windows machine, simply put it in your mac and you should be able to boot to it and use your recovery software to attempt to recover the files.

Comment: That's a nice name you have there.